# How to add more metrics on the country_map in Apache-superset?

Tags: javascript, python, d3.js, apache-superset

I am using `country_map` in [apache-superset](/questions/tagged/apache-superset) for visualization purposes. When zooming in on a polygon, information from the columns appears inside of the polygon, like so:

[image: map]

There is only one available metric option to display:
[image: metric]

Code for the metric update is found on this path:

> superset/assets/src/visualizations/CountryMap/CountryMap.js

Code:

```
const updateMetrics = function (region) {
  if (region.length > 0) {     
    resultText.text(format(region[0].metric));
  }
};
```

The metrics are defined in controls.jsx:

> /superset/static/assets/src/explore/controls.jsx

```
const metrics = {
  type: 'MetricsControl',
  multi: true,
  label: t('Metrics'),
  validators: [v.nonEmpty],
  default: (c) => {
    const metric = mainMetric(c.savedMetrics);
    return metric ? [metric] : null;
  },
  mapStateToProps: (state) => {
    const datasource = state.datasource;
    return {
      columns: datasource ? datasource.columns : [],
      savedMetrics: datasource ? datasource.metrics : [],
      datasourceType: datasource && datasource.type,
    };
  },
  description: t('One or many metrics to display'),
};
const metric = {
  ...metrics,
  multi: false,
  label: t('Metric'),
  default: props => mainMetric(props.savedMetrics),
};
```

Country map is using `metric`, which doesn't allow multiple metrics to be selected, Code found here:

> superset/assets/src/explore/controlPanels/CountryMap.js

```
  controlPanelSections: [
    {
      label: t('Query'),
      expanded: true,
      controlSetRows: [
        ['entity'],
        ['metric'],
        ['adhoc_filters'],
      ],
    },
    {
      label: t('Options'),
      expanded: true,
      controlSetRows: [
        ['select_country', 'number_format'],
        ['linear_color_scheme'],
      ],
    },
  ],
```

The python class of `country_map` is located at viz.py:

```
class CountryMapViz(BaseViz):

    """A country centric"""

    viz_type = 'country_map'
    verbose_name = _('Country Map')
    is_timeseries = False
    credits = 'From bl.ocks.org By john-guerra'

    def query_obj(self):
        qry = super(CountryMapViz, self).query_obj()
        qry['metrics'] = [
            self.form_data['metric']]
        qry['groupby'] = [self.form_data['entity']]
        return qry
```

Changing the code in CountryMap.js and viz.py from `metric` to `metrics` results in the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Documents/superset/superset/superset/viz.py", line 410, in get_df_payload
    df = self.get_df(query_obj)
  File "/Documents/superset/superset/superset/viz.py", line 213, in get_df
    self.results = self.datasource.query(query_obj)
  File "/Documents/superset/superset/superset/connectors/sqla/models.py", line 797, in query
    sql = self.get_query_str(query_obj)
  File "/Documents/superset/superset/superset/connectors/sqla/models.py", line 471, in get_query_str
    qry = self.get_sqla_query(**query_obj)
  File "/Documents/superset/superset/superset/connectors/sqla/models.py", line 585, in get_sqla_query
    elif m in metrics_dict:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

How can I add more metrics to display inside the polygon?

Comment: What did you modify exactly? Could you post your modification to `CountryMap.js` and `viz.py`?

Comment: @gdlmx In `CountryMap.js` I changed `['metric']` to `['metrics']`. I did the same in `viz.py`, at the `CountryMapViz` class, where I just modified `self.form_data['metric']]` to `self.form_data['metrics']]`, in the `query_obj(self)` method.

Answer (score 1):

The direct cause of the error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'` is your modification to file "viz.py":

> `self.form_data['metric']]` to `self.form_data['metrics']]`, in the `query_obj(self)` method.

As you can see in the source code [here](https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/blob/48b7ebea1346820ec68e8c8ae8b3d70c81fc5281/superset/viz.py#L1694), form data `metrics` is a `list` object that contains `metric`, where `metric` is probably a string or other hashable object. In python language, a `list` object is not hashable. Because you replace a hashable object (`metric`) with an unhashable one (`metrics`), an `unhashable type` error is then raised.

The correct way to modify `CoutryMapViz.query_obj()` to accept `metrics` query can be found in the other `Viz` classes. The code section [here](https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/blob/48b7ebea1346820ec68e8c8ae8b3d70c81fc5281/superset/viz.py#L819) is a very nice example:

```
class CalHeatmapViz(BaseViz):

"""Calendar heatmap."""
...

    def query_obj(self):
        d = super(CalHeatmapViz, self).query_obj()
        fd = self.form_data
        d['metrics'] = fd.get('metrics')
        return d
```

Finally, the `CoutryMapViz.query_obj()` method should look like this:

```py
class CountryMapViz(BaseViz):

...

    def query_obj(self):
        qry = super(CountryMapViz, self).query_obj()
        qry['metrics'] = fd.get('metrics')
        qry['groupby'] = [self.form_data['entity']]
        return qry
```

Comment: This change however does not make a difference in the metrics shown inside the polygon. Even if you select more than 1 metric in the form, only the first selected metric will be shown when you hover on or click the polygons

Comment: This is to do with the `get_data` method. You can use the codes in the `CalHeatmapViz.get_data()` function as an example.

Comment: To make the chart display correct, you need to modify the `propTypes` in `CountryMap.js` and `CoutryMapViz.get_data()` in `viz.py`. This is another question that worth to be discussed in another post.

Comment: my question however is not about getting rid of the Type error, but rather about the end result being functional. But regardless, thanks for your contribution and the suggestions in the comment